# Pandas: selecting multiple columns in dataframe by integer

Tags: pandas, dataframe, subset

Assume I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : (1, 2, 3),
                   'b' : (1, 2, 3),
                   'c' : ("one", "two", "three"),
                   'd' : (4, 5, 6),
                   'e' : (4, 5, 6),
                   'f' : (7, 8, 9),
                   'g' : (7, 8, 9),
                   'h' : (7, 8, 9)})
```

I am trying to select the first, third, & fifth until the last columns. Desired output would be:

```
   a      c  e  f  g  h
0  1    one  4  7  7  8
1  2    two  5  8  7  8
2  3  three  6  9  9  9
```

How do I select multiple columns that are not in consecutive manner using integer? I have tried the following:

```
df.iloc[,[0, 3, 5:]]
df.loc[,[0, 3, 5:]]
df.iloc[,[0, 3, 5:len(df.columns)]]
df.loc[,[0, 3, 5:len(df.columns)]]
df.iloc[,[0 + 3 + 5:]]
df.loc[,[0 + 3 + 5:]]
df.iloc[,[0 + 3 + 5:len(df.columns)]]
df.loc[,[0 + 3 + 5:len(df.columns)]]
```

None worked

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for join slicers, python counts from `0`, so for third column need `2` and from `5th` column need `4:`:

```
df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[0, 2, 4:len(df.columns)]]
print (df)
   a      c  e  f  g  h
0  1    one  4  7  7  7
1  2    two  5  8  8  8
2  3  three  6  9  9  9
```

Comment: Lifesaver, if you don't mind, do you also have a solution for numpy data converted through `df.values`?

Comment: @AgnesLee - Do you think `a = df.to_numpy()` and then `arr = a[:, np.r_[0, 2, 4:a.shape[1]]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by flatten a list of list with [any methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) you like.

```py
from pandas.core.common import flatten

df1 = df.iloc[:, list(flatten([[0, 2], range(4, len(df.columns))]))]

df2 = df.iloc[:, np.concatenate([[0, 2], range(4, len(df.columns))])]
```